# Google maps api user can select area

Tags: api, google-maps

I want to create a local map for my city where people can cover area with polygons and get their latitude and longitude

For Example there is a world map and someone come and he wanted to cover us then he can simply cover it and get its latitude and longitude of corners or borders

Is there any way or example i searched about it on google and Site both but didn't get Anything

Sorry I've no Codes i want idea, code or something helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple search yielded http://www.the-di-lab.com/polygon/ and you can find a lot more samples at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery.html.

Unfortunately the above demo is a minified js. But the essential part of drawing a polygon (area) on google maps is to 
1. load the map
2. trap the click events and the position (lat/lon)
3. draw lines
4. Finally when a double click is received, close the polygon

I unfortunately do not have a ready made sample in hand.

Answer (score 6):

The answers here are quite outdated.
Google Maps now have a drawing library, This library allows the user to insert markers, circles, polygons and other types as well.

You can find an example on it [here](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools). And the library reference [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/drawing).
And the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a simpler solution now. From the same [demo gallery link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery.html) that Muthu shared earlier look for [user editable shapes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/user-editable-shapes). Below is a sample code from this link that draws a rectangle and allows user to edit the shape further

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 44.5452, lng: -78.5389},
      zoom: 9
    });

    var bounds = {
      north: 44.599,
      south: 44.490,
      east: -78.443,
      west: -78.649
    };

    // Define a rectangle and set its editable property to true.
    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      bounds: bounds,
      editable: true
    });
    rectangle.setMap(map);
  }
```

Also here is an example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/382gy6ar/3/) that extends above to generalized polygon and below is the code from the link

```
  var editablePolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: coords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    editable: true   });
```

Attached is a screenshot (after dragging one midpoint node in the triangle)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use GeoChart
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart?csw=1. It can cover certain regions or areas